# Pointers in C++, Raw Memory Operations

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a few different questions about the following snippet of code, an example given by one of my professors.

First off, what is Thing t{8,15}? Is this an array of two integers, 8 and 15?
Or is this initializing the x and y values of t (a varialbe of type Thing) to 8, and 15 respectively? 
Second, What is happening on the line:

```
std::cout << "n\t = " << place[0] << ", " << place[1];
```

It looks to me like it is printing the indicies of the variable place, which to my understanding is a pointer to an int, pointing to the integer values at the memory address of t?

Finally, What on earth is happening on this line:

```
 int y = *( int *)(( char *)& t + 4);
```

Here I am lost. Please bear with me, learning pointers and memory

Code im dealing with:

```
struct Thing {
int x , y ;
int* getPlaces () {
    return & x ;
}
};

int main () {

Thing t {8 ,15};
int* place = (int *)& t ;
std :: cout << "\nt = " << place [0] << ", " << place [1];
int y = *( int *)(( char *)& t + 4);
std :: cout << "\nt.y = " << y ;
int* location = t . getPlaces ();
location [0] = 17;
std :: cout << "\nt.x = " << t . x ;

}
```

Comment: `*( int *)(( char *)& t + 4)` is just nasty and breaks *strict aliasing* in a bad way. As does the use of `place`. If your professor gave you that code you should tell him or her that.

Comment: I think the point of this exercise was to run the code yourself and see the results, then use that to gain understanding.

Comment: @SomeProgrammerDude it's ugly as sin, but not a strict aliasing violation because there already is an int object at that memory location.

Comment: @Frank It's a violation because the code treats `t` as an array of two `int` values, which it's not. It doesn't matter that `&t` is pointing to an `int`. `&t` is a pointer to `Thing`, not a pointer to `int`, and that's where it all breaks down. The casting to `char*` *might* solve it, but I'm not really sure about that.

Comment: @SomeProgrammerDude yes, i agree, place is indeed a violation, I was commenting on the first part of your comment only, sorry for the confusion. The casting g to char* does makes it fine, because it's casting to storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{8,15}` is an initializer list. So, `Thing t{8,15}` is the declaration of a variable `t` of type `Thing` initialized with the values 8 and 15. The members are initialized with these values in order of declaration, i.e. x=8 and y=15.

`int* place` is the declaration of a pointer to an int, but in C/C++, a pointer is always also an array. So, you can write `place[0]` for the variable pointed to by `place`, `place[1]` for the variable immediately following and so on. There is no bounds checking, so be sure to know what you do.

`(some_type)` is a (C-style) cast. Casts force the following expression to be interpreted in a certain way. In your example, `&t` takes the address of t. Then this pointer is forced to be interpreted as pointer to a `char` (essentially meaning that each item is a single byte). I.e. when you add 4 to that pointer, you point 4 bytes past. Next (to the left), this entire thing is interpreted as a pointer to an `int`. And finally (the `*` to the very left), the whole thing is dereferenced, yielding whatever was found at that address intepreted as `int`.

Summary: this example is for learning only. NEVER program like this in a real progam. The code depends on `int` being 4 bytes and on the capability of the CPU to allow an `int` on any address. This is not always the case.

Comment: "[P]ointer is always also an array" is very wrong. A pointer is a pointer, an array is an array, and they are different. An array can *decay* to a pointer to its first element though, which is the reason beginners do this mistake.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude agreed. I should have been more precise.

Answer (score 1):

```
Thing t {8 ,15};
```

it is initializing t. x and y are member of t which are initialized to 8 and 15.

place[0] and place[1] will print 8 and 15 as place is pointed to t in previous line,.

```
int y = *( int *)(( char *)& t + 4);
```

t is converted to (char *) and then added 4 and then it is dereferenced after casting to int *. it will print 15.

Comment: it worth noting that adding a virtual method (or declaring the current getPlaces as virtual) breaks everything.